# authorization token changing repeatedly

Tags: python, python-requests, google-chrome-devtools

I wrote a python script which sends POST requests to some particular website. In order to perform this request, I need the authorization token which keeps changing. my current solution is to use Chrome Dev tools (Network tab) to obtain the new token. I was wondering if there is any way to obtain the new token automatically, or any other way to get around this problem.
this is my current code:(Note that in the provided code general text has been replaced with "...")

```
import requests
import json

url = "..."
payload = {...}

headers = {...,
"Authorization": "Bearer ...",
...}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Authorization tokens typically have a lifespan. If you have long-running code you may have to re-acquire a token. The response for such thing will usually indicate in some header what the lifespan of the token is. You can use that to (reasonably) efficiently determine whether you need to refresh it